# Fastest way Calculating Sum of Customers' Orders using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

In my Database I have many customers and I submit each customer's orders.
Now I need to loop through all customers and find the customers who have order more than a target price. i'm using this piece of code:

```
List<int> IDz = new List<int>();
foreach (var customer in db.tblCustomers)
{
    total = 0;
    foreach (var order in db.tblCustomerOrders.Where(x => x.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID))
        total += Convert.ToDouble(order.Amount);

     if (total >= Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text))
         IDz.Add(customer.CustomerID);
}
```

This code will take about more than 15 seconds for about 1500 customers. How Can I make is faster? any suggestion?

Comment: Probably check your db and create an index for CustomerID in your Order tables.

Comment: Linq doesn´t do it "better" or even "faster" as you wanto, it´s just syntactic sugar. To increase the performance your should first use a profiler to verify that your performamce-issues are really related to that code and *if* they are consider to configurate the DB as suggested by mybirthname. The problem on LINQ is that it will do the exact same internally as you already do - looping your rows returned from your database.

Comment: Storing numerical values as strings... I think code just pays you back for such an interesting design :) - [stringly typed code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)... Please clarify why you must do that (especially in comparing `total`) and why you are not doing all operations in DB.

Comment: @HimBromBeere LINQ-to-SQL is likely to do much better than average person's hand-slapped SQL query... which likely be the case here.

Comment: Not sure if this would be faster : total = db.tblCustomerOrders.Where(x => x.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID).Select(x => (double)x.Amount).Sum();

Comment: Find out what part of the code takes the most time to execute. Could some parts of the code run in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, as you have `CustomerID` and `Amount` columns in `tblCustomerOrders`, there is no need to loop through `tblCustomers`. What you have to do is group `tblCustomerOrders` according to `CusotmerID`, find total sum and check if amount is more than input amount, then select `CustomerID`s which meets those criterias. Also, as you do all that stuff at database side (I believe you are using EntityFramework), your query must be way more faster.

```
double inputAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text);
var result = db.tblCustomerOrders
    .GroupBy(m => m.CustomerID)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        CustomerID = g.Key,
        Sum = g.Sum(m => m.Amount)
    })
    .Where(m => m.Sum > inputAmount)
    .Select(m => m.CustomerID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Stranger, no problem there also, just add what filter you need before `GroupBy` method using `When` method

Comment: Thank You Adil, Nice,Clean and Fast. It is Great :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try below approach for calculating the total Amount:

```
double total = db.tblCustomerOrders.Where(x => x.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID).Select(t => t.Amount ?? 0).Sum();
```

Using the null coalescing operator will give you a default of 0 if `t.Amount` is null.

Hope it will help you, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will shorten the query time, by doing the calculation in the query without getting the customers first

```js
 double amnt = Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text);
 List<int> IDz = db.tblCustomers.Where(c => db.tblCustomerOrders.Where(o => o.CustomerID == c.CustomerID).Sum(o => o.Amount) > amnt).Select(c => c.CustomerID).ToList();
```